# Displaying a differnt part of PNG on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have seen a website that has an img tag which refers to a single image in normal state. It displays one part of a PNG and on mouse hover it displays a different part of same PNG image. [In the example page](http://www.fortinet.com/) if you hover the Solution Menu item and then hover on any of sub-item it will display different part of same image in that.

I wish to add the same effect in my wordpress site. How is is done?

Comment: what did you try ? what is exactly your problem ? provide some code...

Comment: [See below to know what he wants - @phron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936563/displaying-a-differnt-part-of-png-on-mouse-hover/21936625#21936625)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS Image Sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/N4jXL/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background:url("http://www.fortinet.com/sites/all/themes/fortinet/images/solution_icons/enterprise_core.png") no-repeat;
}
.div:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are called **CSS Sprites**

You can read more about them [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the position of a background

```
div.myImage
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(/images/sprite.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

div.myImage:hover
{
  background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

It is how [sprites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites) work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're referring to an image sprite. See below for help / info.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, the one that your example is using is a container with a fixed width and height, a hidden overflow and the image inside it so the full image is there but the overflow doesn't show, in the hover event they set a top margin to the image making it to move upwards. This kind of images are called sprites, all the icons are included in the same image (saving http requests) and displayed using their position.

Also, using a margin top, overflow hidden, etc is not the recommended way, the right way is to use the background css property in the container making it easier to control the image viewport position. Another improvement is to use the pseudo-element :before instead of an img tag.